# Proving that $\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\frac{|x+h|-|x|}{h}$ does not exist at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, limits-without-lhopital

In our exam, we are tasked to prove that $U(0)$ does not exist where,

$$U(x) = \lim\limits_{h \to 0}\frac{|x+h|-|x|}{h}$$

What I did was to simplify the function first, so I initially performed the limit operation. That function above is essentially the derivative of $|x|$, so I got,

$$U(x) = \frac{x}{|x|}$$

And after doing $U(0)$, it became

$$U(0) = undefined$$

This completed my proof. My teacher marked it wrong. What is the incorrect step in what I did and what could be the right proof?

Comment: You're right when you say that $U(x)$ is "essentially the derivative of $|x|$"; the problem is that you're not being specific enough. The derivative of $|x|$ is not just $\frac x{|x|}$, it is as follows: $$\begin{cases} \frac x{|x|} & \text{if $x\neq 0$} \\ \text{undefined} & \text{$x=0$}\end{cases}$$
If you had used that definition, you would be more justified in stating that $U(x)$ is undefined. But even then, the point of the question is to show *why* that comes about by calculating the limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You basically did two things in the opposite order as expected, and that allowed a fallacy to creep in.  You were asked first to substitute $x=0$, then evaluate the limit as $h\to 0$.  This is
$$
    U(0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{|0+h| - |0|}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{|h|}{h}
$$
which does not exist.

Instead, you took the limit as $h\to0$, (which does, as you say, compute the derivative at $x$), then asserted that this expression was not defined at $x=0$.  But this line of reasoning is not valid to show that the the original limit does not exist.  For instance, in your problem, replace $|x|$ by $$f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2 \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) & \text{if $x\neq 0$} \\ 0 & \text{$x=0$}\end{cases}$$  Then if $x\neq0$
\begin{align*}
    f'(x) &= 2x \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) + x^2 \cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\cdot \left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\\
    &= 2x \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) - \cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)
\end{align*}
Not only is this undefined at $0$, $\lim_{x\to 0} f'(x)$ does not exist.  But if you first set $x=0$, then take the limit, you get
$$
    \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h) - 0}{h}
    = \lim_{h\to 0} h \sin\left(\frac{1}{h}\right)
    = 0
$$
So $f'(0) =0$.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I am still bothered with the specific case of the function that I have given. In my way of thought, the said function is the derivative itself $(U(x) = \lim\limits_{h \to 0}\frac{|x+h|-|x|}{h})$. Now that function $U(x)$ itself is undefined at a specific point (as I have shown). Doesn't that mean the derivative does not exist at that point too? The equation establishes that their values should be the same, right? To clarify, I did not perform a limit operation with $U(x)$, all I did was just to simplify the right side of the equation, and then plug in $0$.

Comment: @Wilhelm You are saying you "did not perform a limit operation with $U(x)$," but in the question, you write, "What I did was to simplify the function first, so I initially performed the limit operation."

Answer (score 1):

You must *strictly* keep the definition given, so by what you say:

$$H(0)\stackrel?=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{|h|}h$$

and **now** show the above limit doesn't exist by calculating both one-sided limits

Comment: so in this case, 'undefined' does not necessarily mean 'does not exist'? I mean if the function is actually a limit, and that function is undefined at an input, it does not necessarily mean that the function does not exist at that input?

Comment: Question "Why does ... not exist" Your answer "Because it is undefined." This is just a reformulation of the question. Your task was to explain why it does not exist resp. can not defined at this point. Which can be done here by computing the one-sided limits.

Comment: @Wilhelm In this case, I think *the intention* was for you to prove the given function, as a limit, cannot exist at $\;x=0\;$ , and to achieve this you must show the limit doesn't exist *as defined* . Of course, you could give the definition as it is given for $\;x\neq0;$, and then define it arbitrarily at $\;x=0\;$ .

Answer (score 1):

Your first step, that $U(x)=\frac {d|x|}{dx},$ is only true for $x\ne 0.$ So you obtain the result that $\lim_{x\to 0}U(x)$ does not exist. But you were not asked about $\lim_{x\to 0}U(x).$ You were asked about $U(0).$  Your first step says nothing about $U(0).$ You cannot assume that if  $\lim_{x\to 0}U(x)$  does not exist then $U(0)$ doesn't exist.